# Creating objects in bulk takes lot of time even after using Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, object, concurrency, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I am trying to create objects in bulk (`> 4000`), it takes more than 8 seconds.

`allrows` is `list<object[]>` with 4000 records.

```
ConcurrentBag <data> lstdata = new ConcurrentBag <data>();

Parallel.ForEach(allRows, (row) => {
  lstdata.Add(new data() {
          Id = row["NB"],
              ColumnId = row["COLUMN_ID"]],
      Value = row["VALUE"]],
  });
});
```

Please suggest.

Comment: What is the type of `allRows` ?

Comment: Since it has to take locks I doubt Parallel will be faster.  Your threads are just competing with each other.

Comment: @paparazzo is right. Concurent object use internal locks so once a thread is adding an item the other is paused waiting it's turn. You do no get great benefits. You still get few gains as the information is ready for the next iteration but it's not much.

Comment: Try the ctor where you pass a collction.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381771(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: also consider codereview.SE for performance improvement questions

Answer (score -1):

Parallel is not likely to go faster as the need to take locks.

Try using enumerable ctor

```
List<SimpleClass> simpleClassList = new List<SimpleClass>() { new SimpleClass(1, "bob"), new SimpleClass(2, "ken") };
var x = from t in simpleClassList
        select new SimpleClass (t.ID + 10, t.Name);
ConcurrentBag<SimpleClass> simpleClassCB = new ConcurrentBag<SimpleClass>(x);
foreach (var v in simpleClassCB)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"{v.ID}  {v.Name}");
}
```

Comment: How do i convert ParalleLoopResult to IEnumerable<data>

Comment: Also, I am using concurrent bag so that multiple threads can insert in the collection. Later i will be using this collection to initialize other collection.

Comment: OK, I still don't think parallel will make it go faster.

Comment: Here is the whole story, We are getting lot of data >4000 rows from oracle. Reading each row and creating objects was taking lot of time, so we first load all the data in List<object> allrows from oracledbreader,then we process this in loop to create object collection using for loop. Since for loop was taking lot of time, we moved to parallel.foreach and to allow multiple threads insert into same collection we used concurrentbag. once all objects are created in concurrentbag, we move this to our actual collection.